# Prevent an input type box from being typed in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a datepicker with input box. When clicking the box, the calendar widget (Bootstrap Datepicker) shows. I want to prevent that a user can type anything in the box, meaning he is forced to select from the calendar. How to do?
I tried using 'disable' but that disables it all.

```html
<div class="input"><label for="date posted">Date posted</label>
<input class='datepicker' id="date-posted" name="date-posted" placeholder="Enter your date posted" required="" type="text"></div>
```

Comment: And how do you want to open the calendar in that case? or you need not the calendar at all?

Comment: @dhlit - calendar shows only when the box is clicked and user picks date. I just want that user cannot type anything in box, he just has to select from the calendar widget, thats it.

Comment: Probably use `<input readonly class='datepicker' .../>`?

Comment: @raulbaros ah! ok I understand, there are some options for that... I vote for `<input onkeydown="return false" ... />`

Comment: `onkeydown="return false"` would still allow you to paste a date thru mouse!

Comment: @Ishettyl - so 'readonly' would be the better one from the two solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disable the keydown event:

```
<input onkeydown="return false" class='datepicker' id="date-posted" name="date-posted" placeholder="Enter your date posted" required="" type="text"></div>
```

Or if you are using [that bootstrap picker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) then you can make the input readonly and enable the [flag of enableOnReadOnly](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enableonreadonly)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".datepicker").keydown(function() {
    return false;
})
```

Or you can use `readonly` attribute